# Calculating life expectancy from Stmomo object

Tags: r, forecasting, demographics

We have a problem, with which we hope one of you are able to help out with. We want to calculate life expectancy based on our Stmomo object.This is our current code:

```
M7 = m7(link='logit') #set up the used model
M7fitM <- fit(M7, data = NLmale, years.fit = 1970:2014, ages.fit = 60:90, wxt=wxt) # fit it to dutch data
M7forM = forecast(M7fitM, h=100, gc.order=c(1,0,0),gc.include.constnt=TRUE) #forecast for 100years, for males only.
```

So basically we have forecasted mortality rates with an m7 model. But we do not know how to translate this into life expectancies. If anyone would be able to help that will be much appreciated.